# Unsure of what this file is doing

Tags: logging

I recently discovered a text file that I have pasted a copy of below. it seems to be some form of log, but I am unsure of what it is doing. in my opinion it seems to be editing hex in a multitude of files, however I do not know what it does. I am worried it could be malicious.

```
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - Module file name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\gameoverlayrenderer.dll
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - GameID = 391540, OverlayGameID = 391540
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - System page size: 4096
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - Hooking SetCursorPos, GetCursorPos, ShowCursor, SetCursor, and GetCursor
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - Modules at GameOverlayRenderer.dll attach
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 01: UNDERTALE.exe - (00400000 to 00A52000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 02: ntdll.dll - (77100000 to 772A4000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 03: KERNEL32.DLL - (76580000 to 76670000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 04: KERNELBASE.dll - (75070000 to 75293000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 05: WS2_32.dll - (752B0000 to 75313000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 06: RPCRT4.dll - (74FB0000 to 7506F000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 07: d3dx9_43.dll - (74490000 to 7468F000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 08: msvcrt.dll - (76810000 to 768CF000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 09: GDI32.dll - (759C0000 to 759E3000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 10: WININET.dll - (738E0000 to 73D36000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 11: USER32.dll - (76270000 to 7640C000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 12: win32u.dll - (753E0000 to 753F8000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 13: dbghelp.dll - (73630000 to 737B8000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 14: gdi32full.dll - (760B0000 to 76191000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 15: COMDLG32.dll - (75910000 to 759BF000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 16: advapi32.dll - (76430000 to 764AB000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 17: msvcp_win.dll - (75360000 to 753DB000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 18: combase.dll - (75D40000 to 75FC0000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 19: sechost.dll - (75400000 to 75476000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 20: shcore.dll - (764B0000 to 76537000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 21: SHLWAPI.dll - (76200000 to 76245000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 22: SHELL32.dll - (768D0000 to 76E86000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 23: ucrtbase.dll - (76EF0000 to 77010000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 24: ole32.dll - (75FC0000 to 760A3000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 25: OLEAUT32.dll - (76770000 to 76806000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 26: COMCTL32.dll - (73DD0000 to 73FE0000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 27: WINMM.dll - (73360000 to 73388000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 28: gdiplus.dll - (72D40000 to 72EA7000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 29: VERSION.dll - (74F00000 to 74F08000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 30: dbgcore.DLL - (73600000 to 7362B000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 31: IMM32.DLL - (76550000 to 76575000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 32: gameoverlayrenderer.dll - (632A0000 to 633E9000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - 33: PSAPI.DLL - (759F0000 to 759F6000)
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - ----------------------------
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - XInput Hooked XInputEnable Version 13
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - XInput Hooked XInputGetBatteryInformation Version 13
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - XInput Hooked XInputGetCapabilities Version 13
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - XInput Hooked XInputGetDSoundAudioDeviceGuids Version 13
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - XInput Hooked XInputGetKeystroke Version 13
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - XInput Hooked XInputGetState Version 13
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - XInput Hooked XInputGetStateEX Version 13
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - XInput Hooked XInputSetState Version 13
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - Game is using opengl32.dll... hooking.
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - Game is using opengl32.dll... hooking.
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - Game is using dinput8, preparing to hook.
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - DirectInput8Create hook called, 028CC008
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - Game is using D3D9 or D3D9Ex, preparing to hook.
Thu May 04 14:37:28 2023 UTC - hookDirect3DCreate9Ex called
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - IWrapIDirect3D9Ex::CreateDevice hook called (type: 1, behavior flags: 42!)
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Creating D3D9Ex renderer
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Initializing Audio...
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Trying to setup input hook...
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Set input hook...
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - hookDirect3DCreate9Ex called
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Game is using dxgi (dx10/dx11), preparing to hook.
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - hookCreateDXGIFactory called
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Hooking vtable for factory
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - DXGIFactory2_CreateSwapChain already hooked via IDXGIFactory or IDXGIFactory1
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - IWrapIDirect3D9Ex::CreateDeviceEx hook called (type: 4, behavior flags: 40!)
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Creating D3D9Ex renderer
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Releasing all resources for device: 0A7585C0
Thu May 04 14:37:29 2023 UTC - Detaching input hook...
Thu May 04 14:37:30 2023 UTC - Trying to setup input hook...
Thu May 04 14:37:30 2023 UTC - Set input hook...
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC - IAudioClient_Initialize - SUCCEEDED
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC - Audio client initialized: 0x0A7DED30
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC - Device:
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC - Audio client mix format:
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC -  format: 65534
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC -  channels: 2
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC -  samples/sec: 48000
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC -  bytes/sec: 384000
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC -  alignment: 8
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC -  bits/sample: 32
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC -  channel mask: 0x3
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC -  data format: {00000003-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC - Audio hooked
Thu May 04 14:37:32 2023 UTC - Audio client started: 0x0A7DED30, 1
Thu May 04 14:37:33 2023 UTC - Game is using dinput.dll (dinput7), preparing to hook.
Thu May 04 14:37:33 2023 UTC - DirectInputCreateW hook called
Thu May 04 15:11:56 2023 UTC - DInput 028CC008 deleting
Thu May 04 15:11:56 2023 UTC - Found a hooked function in now unloaded module, removing from map.
Thu May 04 15:11:56 2023 UTC - Found a hooked function in now unloaded module, removing from map.
Thu May 04 15:11:56 2023 UTC - Releasing all resources for device: 0919C560
Thu May 04 15:11:56 2023 UTC - Detaching input hook...
Thu May 04 15:11:56 2023 UTC - GameOverlayRenderer.dll detaching
```

I have read through the log, but do not know why it is doing this as the executable it is editing is in no way related to the executable this should be relating to. It would not let me post as plain text, so I had to make it a block of code.

**update** the executable that was asociated with this log has disappeared from my system, I am removing all allowed threats and running a virus scan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: If you don't downloaded and ran the game by yourself (or any human), please check your computer with the following apps (was very helpful when PCs from my clients were infected):

- Malwarebytes Free Antivirus
- Malwarebytes AdwCleaner
- Norton Power Eraser
- Emisoft Emergency Kit
- HitmanPro (for detection no license necessary)
- ESET Online Scanner

Use a program like "Autoruns" to inspect all your Autostart areas and one like "Security Task Manager" to inspect current open processes.

---

Related to your posted file:

Line 1 and line 6 give pretty much information about the culprit:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\gameoverlayrenderer.dll"
and
"Undertale.exe"

Seems to be a game published on Steam in 2015 that was launched with the engine "GameMaker: Studio" (store.steampowered.com/app/391540/Undertale/). Those logs contain performance and functional info for debugging purposes.

The posted file itself is 100% clean because it contains Unicode data only. As for the game, its a common one, so its probably harmless, so nothing to worry - but to verify please upload the exe and dlls on [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) and check the results. If you, or another user on this computer, downloaded and executed the game with intention, the log is permitted to exist. If VirusTotal has not many red flags, your computer almost can not be infected by it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, i had done so and the only things that appeared were trojans that i had allowed previously. Looking deeper into the files, all the .dll files appear to only give the original file asInvoker access, so i do not understand why it is adding and manipulating hex codes from beyond the executable it should be, as UNDERTALE.exe was not the file i had originally extracted and was in no way related to UNDERTALE.

Comment: I can not say for sure what this is about (especially I do not know the whole story behind it), but if you do not placed a file called Undertale.exe in this directory, it can be considered as either placed by another user (if there are any other users who login on your computer) or automatically by another app which makes it a malware or PUP at least.

Comment: As for the EXE and DLLs please upload them to www.virustotal.com and let them scan. If there are more than about 4 detections (few can be false positives), chance of infection is increased - in this case please create a bootable medium with "Avira Rescue System" and/or one with "ESET SysRescue Live" and boot from this instead of windows to scan your system off-demand.
But even if www.virustotal.com has no or very few detections, please delete those EXE/DLLs if you do not need them.
That is everything I can do for you.

Comment: Oh, one formal thing: I appreciate your "thanks", but on Stackoverflow you should upvote my answer (arrow buttons) then. If your questions could be answered by me and you feel satisfied, please click the green check additionally.

Comment: I would if I could, however I do not have enough reputation points at the current moment in time, however I will upvote it as soon as I can.